# jQuery: how to select the exact element of the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure I've formulated my question well, hope the details will cover the issues.

So, I'm building an "artificial" full-height slide-like submenu, and I have an empty container there:

```
<section class="masking_sublevel">

</section>
```

Further, I have a bunch of `ul` elements in my HTML that are hidden by default in their containing section:

I'm **updating** the HTML part with a more complete piece:

```
<div id="sldbr_overlay" class="newully">
        <section class="masking_sublevel">

        </section>
        <ul class="sidebar_bumenu">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Beauty <i class="fa fa-chevron-right bu_chevright"></i>
                           <i class="fa fa-chevron-down bu_chevdown"></i>
                </a>
                    <section class="hidden_ul">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Aerobics</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pilates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Yoga</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Massage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Peeling</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bikini Area Sugaring</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Piercing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tattoo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shaping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sauna</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mud SPA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Needle Therapy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shaping</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Leech Therapy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Thai Massage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wushu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </section>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Computers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Construction</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Financial</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Food <i class="fa fa-chevron-right bu_chevright"></i>
                         <i class="fa fa-chevron-down bu_chevdown"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="hidden_ul">
                    <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cheboorackee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Khash</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pork</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hamburgers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Greek Salad</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BBQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tortillas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spaghetti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pasta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ice Cream</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jelly Sugar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lolly Pop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cupcakes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tourism</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="pzik">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle=".sidebar_wrapper" id="sidebar-toggle_abs">
                <img src="svg/filter.svg" class="filter_icon hvr-wobble-bottom">
            </a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="go-2-top" class="gotop_chevron">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So, what I'm doing is selecting the above mentioned `ul` and put it within the empty section on a hover event and emptying it on a mouseleave, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var dropdownLi = $('li.dropdown');
    var maskingSubLvl = $('.masking_sublevel');
    var importedUl = $('.masking_sublevel ul');

    var hiddenUl = $('.hidden_ul ul');


    $(dropdownLi).on('mouseover',function(){

        $(hiddenUl).appendTo(maskingSubLvl);
        $(maskingSubLvl).css('display','block');

    });

    $(dropdownLi).on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(maskingSubLvl).css('display','none');
        $(importedUl).empty();

    $(maskingSubLvl).on('mouseenter',function(){
            $(this).css('display', 'block');

    });

  });

});
```

The problem is that with this piece of code I probably select just the first `ul` with the class of `.hidden_ul'`, since as I hover on the other items (randomly), it keeps on loading the content of the first list. How can I select the VERY `ul` element with the same class that I'm currently hovering?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just give them ID's and use that instead? Like `hidden1`etc, then get the element like this: `var hiddenUl = $('#hidden1');`

Comment: what's the structure of your HTML .. does each 'li.dropdown' has its own hidden_ul & masking_sublevel ?? Try adding a JSFiddle example

Comment: This can be done easily if you show us complete `html`. I can't find you `li` with class `.dropdown`?

Comment: Use `$(this)` to access the element you're hovering over, and go from there.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, I've updated the HTML part, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to traverse from the element that has mouseover to the parent ul, which is a child of the grand-parent `.hidden_ul`

```
// remove this, it has no context to each drop down 
// var hiddenUl = $('.hidden_ul ul');

$(dropdownLi).on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).closest('.hidden_ul').children('ul').appendTo(maskingSubLvl);

    // though if there are no child uls in your lis, this will do
    $(this).closest('ul').appendTo(maskingSubLvl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `hidden_ul` is direct `child` of `.dropdown` you need to get it using its parent context as below:

```
$(dropdownLi).on('mouseover',function(){
    var hiddenUl=$(this).find('.hidden_ul')[0];//find the child
    $(hiddenUl).appendTo(maskingSubLvl);
    $(maskingSubLvl).css('display','block');
});
```

---

**Update**

Instead of `appendTo` try keeping changing the `html` of `.maskingSubLvl` so that no need to remove the content again before appending another. For Ex:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xqf594c0/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dropdownLi = $('li.dropdown');
    var maskingSubLvl = $('.masking_sublevel');
    var importedUl = $('.masking_sublevel ul');

    $(dropdownLi).on('mouseover',function(){
        $(maskingSubLvl).css('display','block');
        var hiddenUl = $(this).find('.hidden_ul ul').clone(); //clone the content
        $(maskingSubLvl).html(hiddenUl);
    });

    $(dropdownLi).on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(maskingSubLvl).css('display','none');
    });

    $(maskingSubLvl).on('mouseenter',function(){
            $(this).css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```